# the most efficient way to do aggregation with null value?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables, and I want to join the two table and do sum operation on their columns.

table 1

```
id  value
1    100
2    101
3    102
4    103
```

table 2

```
id  value
2    201
3    202
```

I want add the two value column, and if there is null, then it is 0. The return table looks like

```
id  value
1   100
2   302
3   304
4   103
```

What is the most simple way to handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value + IFNULL(t2.value, 0) AS value
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id;
```

Comment: ISNULL, not "IFNULL"

Apart from that typo,  this works fine

Comment: @DavidBridge [Not a typo.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: Sorry shmosel. I gather you are using MySQL?
I am on SQL Server. I don't think the question stipulates either (or I missed that) so I suppose these comments might help someone.

Comment: @DavidBridge Yes, note the tag on the question.

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point mate. Thanks for that. I totally missed that one.

Have a look at my other response. I would like to know what you think and if its relevant to MySQL. If not I'll remove it.